# Prove/Disprove: Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a function. Do we have $f(A^c) = (f(A))^c ?$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

let $X$  and $Y$  be two  sets  where $A \subset X $. Let $f : X \rightarrow  Y$ be  a  function. Do we  have  $f(A^c) = (f(A))^c ?$

My attempt : I think yes, I take $ A= [0, \infty)$ , $X=Y= \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = x$ Now $ f( \mathbb{R} / A ) = (f(A))^c$

I thinks  im not on the right track

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Comment: Once again, if you think the answer yes, you must provide a general proof, *not* a case for which the statement holds.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri actually my analysis is  very weak......Im only looking example

Comment: Cases **can** be valuable to give you an intuition with respect to whether the statement should be true or not, or about why it fails. But in this scenario, trivial cases are usually not very helpful. Your case essentially takes $f$ out of the question so there's little insight gained here. Consider different cases, like say, $f$ not into, $f$ not onto, $f$ periodic, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If indeed $f(A^\complement)=f(A)^\complement$ then: $$f(X)=f(A\cup A^\complement)=f(A)\cup f(A^\complement)=f(A)\cup f(A)^\complement =Y$$

Telling us that $f$ is surjective.

Draw conclusions.

Comment: OKs that mean if $f$ will not onto ,then given above statement will not hold @drhab

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\Bbb R$, $Y=[0,+\infty)$, $f(x)=x^2$, $A = Y$ then $f[A^c]=(0, +\infty), f[A]=Y$, so $(f[A])^c = \emptyset$.

> Theorem: Suppose $f:X \to Y$ obeys $\forall A \subseteq X: f[A^\complement]= f[A]^\complement$. Then $f$ is a bijection.

First not that $f$ must be onto: $$f[X]=f[\emptyset^\complement] = f[\emptyset]^\complement= \emptyset^\complement= Y$$ by plugging in $A=\emptyset$.

Suppose $x_1 \neq x_2$ exist in $X$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Call the common image point $p$. Then $p \in f[\{x_1\}^\complement]$, as witnessed by $x_2$ while $p \notin f[\{x_1\}]^\complement = \{p\}^\complement$ contradicting the property for $A=\{x_1\}$.

So any non-bijection will give a counterexample, and for a bijection $f$, the property $\forall A \subseteq X: f[A^\complement]= f[A]^\complement$ does hold. So the property is equivalent to being a bijection.